# how to access Search and Offline Availability in office 365

Tags: powershell, search, office-365, pnp-powershell

how to access Search and Offline Availability in office 365, to disable search results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since August 2016, the `ExcludeFromOfflineClient` property is exposed via CSOM.

Ensure that you have that latest CSOM dll or atleast a version after August 2016.

After that you can run the below script in SharePoint online powershell to set the search and offline availability:

```
Add-Type -Path "<insert path>\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "<insert path>\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.runtime.dll" 

# Variables with prompts 
$siteUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Site Collection URL" 
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter username"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString 

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl)  
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)  
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials 

$rootWeb = $ctx.Web 
$ctx.Load($rootWeb) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

# Update root site     
$rootWeb.ExcludeFromOfflineClient=$true 
$rootWeb.Update() 
$ctx.Load($rootWeb) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: hi @prabhatkatoch, did you try this solution ?

Comment: How to fetch **"Indexing Site Content"** property from Search and Offline Availability in office 365 from CSOM...?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the site from appearing on search results by doing the following:

1. On the site, click **Settings** > **Site Settings**
2. Under **Search**, click **Search and offline availability**
3. At **Indexing Site Content** select **No**
4. Save the changes

This defines, that the site will not be visible in the search results. Note, that this also affects the subsites below the site if there are any.